# Object to IEnumerable<double>

Tags: c#

I never expected this question to give me so much trouble, but after a few hours of experimentation and Google searches, here I am. I have a `Hashtable` where the values are arrays of `int` and `double`. I want to process the contents of the `Hashtable` as arrays of `double`. Everything I have tried gives me an invalid cast exception.

Here are some examples of what I've tried:

```
var h = new Hashtable() { { "Integer", new[] { 1, 2 } }, { "Double", new[] { 2.0, 3.0 } };

// Just cast it to a double
var d = (h.Keys as IEnumerable).Cast<double>(); // Invalid cast exception when enumerating

// Maybe casting to an object first will resolve the casting issues?
var d1 = (h.Keys as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().Cast<double>(); // Invalid cast exception when enumerating
```

How can I work with all the values in `h` as doubles?

Comment: Don't use `HashTable`, or any other non-generic data structure.  It just causes a million different problems.

Comment: _"We don't recommend that you use the Hashtable class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class."_ [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) ...  [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable)

Comment: @Servy and @quaabamm are absolutely right. Don't use `HashTable`! However, even using the proper `Dictionary<K, V>`, you can still write `new Dictionary<string, dynamic[]>().Keys.Cast<double>()` so... why in the world would you try to do that when you know the keys are strings because you are setting them?

Comment: @AluanHaddad When the data structure is statically typed you no longer need to cast things to get them to be the type you need, so you don't get errors for casting to the wrong type, because you no longer have any casts.  *Removing the need to cast* is the correct solution, not changing what you cast to.

Comment: @Servy, I completely agree/understand. I am asking why he wrote `(h.Keys as IEnumerable).Cast<double>()` in the first place. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thety're trying to cast the types because they used a data structure that's not statically typed so, if you did actually want to use it (which you shouldn't) you *would* have to cast anything you got out of it.

Comment: @Servy Yes. Quite. Indeed. But I am trying to understand why the OP is trying to cast convert keys he knows are strings into doubles. I'm am 1000% in favor of generic collections, but you can still do weird things and I his code is weird.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Clearly it's a mistake.  A mistake that's much easier to make when you're forced to cast everything and don't have a compiler to tell you when you mistake the type of something.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think he confused Keys for Values.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a Dictionary instead

```
var h = new Dictionary<string, object[]>() {
    {"Integer", new object[] {1, 2, 3}},
    {"Double", new object[] {1.0, 2.0,3.0}
}};

var doubles = h.SelectMany(i => i.Value)
               .Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", doubles));
```

To avoid unnecessary conversions, you could allow the compiler do the hard work for you like this

```
var h = new Dictionary<string, double[]>() {
    {"Integer", new [] {1d, 2, 3}},
    {"Double", new [] {1.0, 2.0,3.0}
}};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", h.SelectMany(i => i.Value)));
```

Or if you need to keep your data structure using a `HashTable`

```
var h = new Hashtable() { { "Integer", new[] { 1, 2 } }, { "Double", new[] { 2.0, 3.0 } } };

var doubles = h.Values.OfType<int[]>()
                    .SelectMany(i => i).Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i))
                    .Concat(h.Values.OfType<double[]>().SelectMany(i => i));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", doubles));
```

However, I recommend switching to Dictionaries since it's a generic collection (System.Collections.Generic namespace), it's faster and you can manipulate easily the data by using `Linq` syntax.

Comment: Why are you storing values in array of type object[] ? Why not using the precise type ?

Comment: Because the values are not the same type and the dictionary has to specify one. You would need separate collections, with no dictionary, if using generics.

Comment: @insane_developer They're all supposed to be doubles though.  So they *are* supposed to be a single type.

Comment: Nice! I'd add an explanation of why not `Hashtable`, for OP's benefit and completeness of the answer. I know there are links in comments, but I think it'd be helpful as an explanation in the answer as well.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 are integers not doubles.

Comment: @Servy according to OP he has two different types. That's why I went and use the object[]

Comment: I mean 1.0 == 1, so you could straight away use double as the collection type. double is a super-set for integers.  So double[] is a good choice for this case and it will allow to avoid those horrible casts and conversions.

Comment: @LuisLavieri But does he need them to be of two different types?  They specifically stated that they *want* them to all be doubles.  That they aren't of the same type is *precisely the problem trying to be solved*, and it's one that can be done statically, rather than creating a type in the improper format and then re-creating it at runtime into what you wanted all along..

Comment: Don't know. Those were OP's requirements. He probably simplified his example and maybe he is dealing with lots of decimals or he just wants to process everything in a single loop. Who knows!? :)

Comment: @LuisLavieri The requirements were to process the contents of the arrays as doubles.  If you assume the structure's type and contents are part of the requirements (which isn't stated, but is sort of implied), then you've already changed them by changing the type of the data structure and changing the types of the arrays inside of it.  Either you think the original data structure is a requirement or you don't.  You've even already changed the types of the arrays inside of it, so if you're going to do that, you might as well change it to the type they need it to be.

Comment: Imho I think it's worth mentioning that Dictionary<string, double[]> is a good and efficient candidate for this case. You can keep your solution as it is and mention this as a remark.

Comment: @Servy I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The `Keys` property of your `HashTable` are nothing but strings "Integer" and "Double", so unfortunately, yes, trying to cast the string "Integer" into a double throws an exception.

Try using the `Values` property of the `HashTable` instance. Each value has its own type. In this case, `int[]`, and `double[]`, as such `h.Values` is nothing but an `ICollection`, which also implements an `IEnumerable`, meaning that, as you may know, you can use the Linq Cast extension method on.

Although worth mentioning I'd never recommand that you do it this way (as many proposed, using an `IDictionary` may be a lot more convenient), I think the answer to your question is the following, since both `int` and `double` implement the `IComparable` interface :

```
 h.Values
  .Cast<Array>()
  .SelectMany(a => a.Cast<IComparable>())
  .Select(c => Convert.ToDouble(c))
```